# Where is Imam Mahdi now? (Shia's viewpoint)

Tags: shiism, imam-mahdi

I was wondering where Imam Zaman (Mahdi) is living now?

Actually I want to know more information about his precise location. (Shia view)

*Note: Imam Mahdi (a.j.) is the last (12th) Imam of Shia who ...*

Comment: you should not be wondered of Imam Mahdi's long life because Allah that had a life to Prophet Nouh (pbuh) more than 950 years, (according to 35th Aya of Nisa surah) of course, can give to Imam Mahdi (pbuh) a long life to.

Comment: @FatemehBaqeri, u r right. of course I didn't mean if Imam Mahdi is alive, I would know where he is now if he is alive. Otherwise I believe that he is alive now as you mentioned the  the35th Ayah(verse) ...  Thnx for your attention anyhow.

Comment: just a small inquiry... Do sunnis believe in Imam Mahdi???

Comment: As far as I know, a group of them believe in him, and there are many other Sunni who seemingly believe in a person whose name is Mahdi or a perhaps a person who would be considered as the savior...  but apparently there are some discussion in circumstances...

Comment: I found a nice related site concerning your inquiry, which is not in English. Could u tell me which of the following languages are you familiar with?  Arabic? Spanish? French? Turkish? Urdu? (as the available sites which u can read them concerning ur inquiry)

Comment: Dear Wiser, e.g. I show a related issue with your inquiry here (in Spanish & Turkish). (Unfortunately I could not find it in other main languages such as English, Germany, French and so on). 
http://www.islamquest.net/tr/archive/question/fa1708  /   http://www.islamquest.net/es/archive/question/fa1708  /

Comment: another small inquiry... the Imam Mahdi which Sunnis believe who will come in the last time, is he the same person , your 12th Imam, how can you prove that? Only English please. And also I wold like to read some interesting story about his disappearance from a good source(Again only English please)

Comment: I think no body can help you in this because the authenticity of Mahdi's birth and/or his hiding, in itself, has been a debatable issue from the very beginning in the Shia tradition.

Answer (score 4):

According to a narration from Sheikh Muhammad bin Ibrahim Nomani, al-Ghaybah al-Nomani p. 189:

> The owner of this task [The Hazrat Mahdi] will have a resemblance to
>   Yusuf (as).And I said: It is as if you are telling us of a
>   disappearance or astonishment. He said: The brothers of YUSUF were
>   clever and intelligent. They were children of a prophet. They came
>   into the presence of Yusuf and talked to him, and addressed him and
>   shopped with him. They did not recognize him, even though they were
>   his brothers; until he introduced himself to them and said, “I am
>   Yusuf.” Then they recognized him. So how will this lost and aimless
>   people deny that Allah can hide His Hujjat [Hazrat Mahdi (as)] from
>   them? Yusuf was the ruler of Egypt, and his father was 18 days’
>   journey away. Had Yusuf wished to make his presence known, he had the
>   power to do so. I swear to Allah that when they gave the good news to
>   Yaqub (as) he went to Egypt in 9 days, and if Allah applies the very
>   same process to His Hujjat [Hazrat Mahdi (as)], why does this nation
>   deny this?

---

Or in a similar Hadith Imam Jafar al Sadiq (a.s.) (as the 6th Imam of Shi'a) says the same but adding this to it as well:

> He walks in your markets or on your carpets...( meaning that he isn't
>   in the skies or in the caves or another dimension, He is right were
>   the people are, and from time to time he visits the righteous people)

**Meaning that he is among us, but we just don't see know him!**

Comment: would you please cite the source of the above-mentioned hadith of Imam Sadiq? Actually has it the same source as the first hadith as you cited "Sheikh Muhammad bin Ibrahim Nomani, al-Ghaybah al-Nomani "? Anyhow, the mentioned hadith of Imam Sadiq was interesting and helpful about his location that made it more clear more men.

Answer (score 0):

Where is Imam Mahdi now?
Few Muslims say: Imam Asr, the son of Imam Hassan Askari, who was born in 256, was promoted from this world to the world of "Horqlia" and whenever, the type of humanity reached the age of puberty and left the darkness of this world and the talent to meet and He saw the Imam of the Age, he will see that Imam.
That Imam goes from place to place to perform his duties and has been seen in various cities and places according to authentic anecdotes. Medina, Mecca, Najaf, Kufa, Karbala, Kazemin, Samarra, Mashhad and Qom are among them. .
And at some times and occasions it is present in a sacred place.

Ref: https://namnak.com/%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%84-%D8%B2%D9%86%D8%AF%DA%AF%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%B2%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86.p46600