# Where will Imam Mahdi appear from? (Shia view)

Tags: shiism, imam-mahdi

It is considered as the belief of Shia school of jurisprudence that Imam Mahdi as the last Imam of Shia and likewise as savior of the world (by the intention of Allah) will appear at the time that the world is full of oppression (plenty of oppression). Actually apparently there are relatively a similar belief in some other sects as well (somewhat, not exactly). I also have heard that he is going to appear from Kaaba. But I am not certain regarding this matter. Would you please illustrate where will be the place of his appearance?

*(Note: I am looking for an authentic tradition regarding the precise place where he will appear from (Shia view))*

Comment: What makes you think you can get better answers than the last time you asked @ http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12846/where-is-imam-mahdi-now-shias-viewpoint?rq=1 (where is he == where will he be).

Comment: Uh-huh, you mentioned a nice point. So, I asked it, since there is a basic difference between these 2 questions, (although they seem to be the same (as u @mate mentioned). Actually (the linked question which you presented, is asking regarding its current living question), ___ but this question is asking about the appearance location of him (when he want to appear to help saving the world (by the intention of Allah and helping good people).   ___ Let me know if you didn't find out what I said.  ////  Well done, you mentioned a nice point. Good luck mate.

Comment: @mate, as a related helpful issues: https://www.al-islam.org/search/site/mahdi

Answer (score 2):

In order to presenting a brief answer, I can say that according to the narration(s), that quoted from Mofzal, he mentioned: I asked Imam Sadiq (a.s.) about the place of appearance of Hadhrat Mahdi. So according to the answer of Imam Sadiq (a.s.) it indicates that the place of the appearance of Imam Zaman (Hadhrat Mahdi) is from Mecca. And in another part of the hadith, it indicates for his situation (kaabah).

---

**Sources:**

- [Shabestan.ir](http://Shabestan.ir/detail/news/407410)
- The book of "Haj wa Mahdaviat, Hussain Elahi Nejad, Ma'shar"